# PHP mysql_num_rows WHERE this equals this

Tags: php

Is it possible to do something like the WHERE clause in a mysql_num_rows statement in PHP? For example, say I have the column "number" in my database. I want to use mysql_num_rows($number) to display how many rows have the number 1. I know the other ways to do this, but it would be much much easier for what I'm doing to be able to use mysql_num_rows with a WHERE clause.

Comment: Look into `COUNT()` in your mysql queries. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: mysql_num_rows returns count of rows, returned by the previous query, it has nothing to do with SQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM tablename WHERE rowname = 1
```

With this query you **don't need** `mysql_num_rows` which is *overhead* for cases when you don't need the data itself but the number of rows.

Comment: Haha, I can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks :)